# *nix `free` or DOS `mem` equivalent for Windows 7 (64-bit)

Tags: windows-7, command-line, memory, 64-bit

On ***nix** systems, `free` displays the total amount of free and used memory in the system. From my research, the DOS `mem` command is similar, but it is not available on 64-bit versions of Windows 7. Is there a built-in alternative for the `mem` command?

Comment: What a glaring omission...

Comment: Maybe `mem` can't handle [192 GB of RAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7)?

Comment: Or maybe they just couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: @iglvzx: Seeing that `mem.exe` is a 16-bit MS-DOS executable, you are probably right.

Comment: `mem` isn't useful on 32 bit windows either since it only reports the status of the 16 bit dos virtual machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that all of these return kilobytes.

#### `wmic` method

```
wmic os get TotalVisibleMemorySize,FreePhysicalMemory
```

I'm not sure TotalVisibleMemorySize is correct, but it does *appear* to show physical memory on my system.

---

#### VBScript method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
    & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colSettings = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
For Each objOperatingSystem in colSettings 
    Wscript.Echo "Available Physical Memory: " & _
        objOperatingSystem.FreePhysicalMemory
Next
```

---

#### PowerShell method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> ```
> # Get-FreeMemory.ps1
> # Sample using PowerShell
> # 1st sample from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394587
> # Thomas Lee
>
> $mem = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
>
> # Display memory
> "System : {0}" -f $mem.csname
> "Free Memory: {0}" -f $mem.FreePhysicalMemory
> ```
>
> This script produces the following output:
>
> ```
> PS C:\foo> .\get-freememory.ps1
>   System : COOKHAM8
>   Free Memory: 2776988
> ```

#### PowerShell condensed (called from cmd)

```
powershell.exe -c (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).FreePhysicalMemory
```

Comment: As per the [specs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394239(v=vs.85).aspx), TotalVisibleMemorySize gives the amount of memory visible to the OS, which is physical memory minus whatever is reserved by hardware.